# Some x86 ASM Reference/Tutorials?

Tags: reference, x86, assembly

I'm trying to find some references in regards to x86 Assembly languages. Tutorials/Examples to help my understanding.
-Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- [Programming from the Ground Up](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf) (free book, highly recommended)
- [x86 Assembly](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly) (wikibooks.org)
- [Essential Resources for x86 Programmers](http://learn86.awardspace.co.uk/)

Comment: yea, I've been reading the x86 wikibook

Comment: - The first one is great for basic understanding - the programming from ground up book.
- x86 Assembly wikibooks is perfect if you know some basics and want a good reference.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [**Roby's PC Assembly Tutorial Lesson**](http://web.archive.org/web/20091027095925/http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Park/3230/x86asm/asmles01.html). It's also available for [download](http://web.archive.org/web/20091027095929/http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Park/3230/download/index.html). It contains diagrams and examples.

*"This assembly lesson is for x86 specific, i.e. for Intel 8088, 80286, 80386, etc. Yes, it is compatible with your Pentium or Pentium III. AMD users could also use this tutorial as well because I cover only the basics. I assume that you have some grasp on some programming language like Pascal, C or C++. I don't want to go over the basic concepts of programming all over again."*

- **Preliminary lesson -- Low Level Basic Concepts**
    Talks about registers, flags, memory, stacks, and interrupts. Don't worry about that too much. You might be confused with so many concepts. However, as you follow the lesson, I think every concepts should be clear enough.
- **Chapter 1 -- COM program structure**
    Begin your journey in assembly by observing the simplest program structure.
- **Chapter 2 -- Variables in Assembly**
    Discover the unique concept of variables in assembly language. The notion is far different than that of the normal high level programming language. I also explain how mov instruction works.
- **Chapter 3 -- Arithmetic Instructions**
    How can we perform some arithmetic in assembly?
- **Chapter 4 -- Bitwise Logic, part 1**
    Using and, or, and xor to perform various logical tasks, including bit masking and flipping.
- **Chapter 5 -- Bitwise Logic, part 2**
    Bit shifting and rolling can be useful in aiding bit masking set forth in the next chapter.
- **Chapter 6 -- Branching**
    Branch is essential for all programs. Let's try some assembly branching instructions to improve the logic of our programs.
- **Chapter 7 -- Loop**
    The loop instruction in assembly can be useful to resemble higher level programming language construct.
- **Chapter 8 -- Interrupt Essentials**
    Using common system interrupt services to do screen output and takes input.
- **Chapter 9 -- Stacks**
    Using push and pop and knowing how the stack behaves. Some details about tiny memory mode is explained here.
- **Chapter 10 -- Making Subroutines**
    Using subroutines to mimic structured programming approach.
- **Chapter 11 -- Macros**
    Using macros.
- **Chapter 12 -- Array Access**
    See how assembly provides a very crude array access instructions.
- **Chapter 13 -- Basic String Instruction**s
    Using various string instructions: movs, lods, cmps, scas, and stos.
- **Chapter 14 -- Structures**
    Using structures like the ones in high-level languages. The structure in assembly is equivalent to struct in C/C++ and record in Pascal.
- **Chapter 15 -- A Bit of Theory**
    Addressing modes and memory modes explained plus Computer Architecture 101.

Comment: Note this is for 16bit proccecors

Answer (score 4):

The best, most comprehensive source of Assembly I've seen is the "[Art of Assembly Language](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Windows/index.html)" book. It's a free download, in several versions.

Comment: if you're really interested in learning assembler then you'd know that anything that uses "high level assembly" is a waste of time, skip this book and look for something that will teach you the low level assembly.Assembly Language for Intel-Based Computers by Kip Irvine is a pretty decent book

Answer (score 3):

For reference, the [Intel IA-32 reference manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) are the definitive source.

Comment: IIRC there is a IA-32 only version of those PDF's (I've got a copy at home). does anyone know where there is a link to them?

Answer (score 2):

I find that [Professional Assembly Language](http://www.amazon.ca/Professional-Assembly-Language-Richard-Blum/dp/0764579010) to be a good start.