# How to analyze the function call (sub_41A1b8) for solving crackme with IDA Pro?

Tags: reverse-engineering, cracking, ida

Please, prompt where there is a check of a condition in a code? How to define, what the password from a crackme is "Benadryl" in IDA Pro? As I understood, there is a call of the "call sub_4038D0" function if over the password correct, we jump on loc_42D555. Help to understand how it works?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jz short loc_42D555` jumps to `loc_42D555` if the zero flag is set. Otherwise it executes the next instruction.

Note that the next instruction is where the failure string ("Wrong code DUDE") is referenced.  Also note that `loc_42D555` is the address where the success string ("Thanks you made...") is referenced.

So if the zero flag is set at the `jz short loc_42D555` instruction, you probably solved the crackme.

In the preceding instruction, the `sub_41A1b8` function is called.  Most likely this function sets the zero flag if the strings referenced in `eax` and `edx` (in this case, your input string and "Benadryl") are equal, but you would need to analyze the `sub_41A1b8` function to know this for sure.

To understand this, you'll need to learn x86 assembly.  There are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214734/some-x86-asm-reference-tutorials) [of](http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroX86.html) [tutorials](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) out there to help you get started.

Comment: Thank you very much. It turns out, it is necessary to step into sub_41A1b8 function? After all it can be done in IDA? Or only in OllyDbg? Sorry, that I am a dummy in this question. I will study more :(

Comment: To know for sure what was happening in the `sub_41A1B8` function, yes, you would need to analyze that function. You could step in with a debugger such as OllyDbg or just double-click on the function name in IDA.  That being said, the value of this exercise is completely lost if you don't learn the basics of x86 assembly first.  You won't be able to definitively understand the function otherwise.