# Binary bomb statements clarification

Tags: gdb, binary-bomb

I am trying to use gdb debugger to solve the binary bomb and I am stuck at these two statements.

I just want to know what does these statements mean.

```
cmp    $0x1,%eax
cmpl   $0x1f5,0x1c(%esp)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know what does these statements mean. cmp $0x1,%eax cmpl $0x1f5,0x1c(%esp)

The first one compares value in register `EAX` with 1. The second compares value stored in memory (on the stack) with a constant `0x1f5`.

Given your question, you should likely read one of the [many available assembly programming tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214734/some-x86-asm-reference-tutorials) before you attempt to make further progress on the original problem.